# 2 bits size variable

Tags: c++, size, bit

I need to define a struct which has data members of size 2 bits and 6 bits.
Should I use `char` type for each member?Or ,in  order not to waste a memory,can I use something like `:2`\ `:6` notation? 
how can I do that?
Can I define a typedef for 2 or 6 bits type?

Comment: What about using `std::bitset<char>` ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char SixBits:6;
    unsigned char TwoBits:2;
} tEightBits;
```

and then use:

```
tEightBits eight;
eight.SixBits = 31;
eight.TwoBits = 3;
```

But, to be honest, unless you're having to comply with packed data external to your application, or you're in a *very* memory constrained situation, this sort of memory saving is not usually worth it. You'll find your code is a lot faster if it's not having to pack and unpack data all the time with bitwise and bitshift operations.

---

Also keep in mind that use of any type other than `_Bool`, `signed int` or `unsigned int` is an issue for the implementation. Specifically, `unsigned char` may not work everywhere.

Comment: Can I define a typedef for 2 or 6 bits type?

Comment: No, you can only do this inside structs.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably best to use `uint8_t` for something like this. And yes, use [bit fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field):

```
struct tiny_fields
{
  uint8_t twobits : 2;
  uint8_t sixbits : 6;
}
```

I don't think you can be sure that the compiler will pack this into a single byte, though. Also, you can't  know how the bits are ordered, within the byte(s) that values of the the struct type occupies. It's often better to use explicit masks, if you want more control.

Comment: +1, but I think it's better to use `unsigned char` than `uint8_t`. The latter can never be smaller than `unsigned char`, so it doesn't save any space. And it's permitted not to exist at all. Using `uint8_t` is just a way of statically asserting `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: Keep in mind bitsets/bit fields will be slower then `chars`.  That's because to write to the bit field, you need to read enclosing byte, update it, then write it back (read-modify-write cycle). Not worth the effort, unless you are under extreme memory pressure.

Comment: @Noor, probably because it's guaranteed to be 8 bits (in systems that support 8 bits), something you can't say for a char.

Comment: @rburny: it's not just about speed vs. storage, though. `sixbits` does modulo-64 arithmetic without writing `&0x3F` all over the place. If you want a 6 bit integer type, then bit fields are the way to get one.

Comment: In fairness, you're almost certainly still doing `&0x3f` all over the place, it just doesn't appear in your source code :-) That still might be reason enough to use it of course, since readability is a big thing for me.

Comment: @paxdiablo: sure, the compiler is masking like crazy. I think computer scientists call the technique "abstraction" ;-)

Comment: Can I define a typedef for 2 or 6 bits type?

Comment: @Yakov: Unfortunately no, and you also can't declare variables of bit-field type. So it's a second-class citizen.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer shift operators and some macros over bit fields, so there's no "magic" left for the compiler. It is usual practice in embedded world.

```
#define SET_VAL2BIT(_var, _val) ( (_var) | ((_val) & 3) )
#define SET_VAL6BIT(_var, _val) ( (_var) | (((_val) & 63)  << 2) )

#define GET_VAL2BIT(_var) ( (_val) & 3)
#define GET_VAL6BIT(_var) ( ((_var) >> 2) & 63 )

static uint8_t my_var;

<...>
SET_VAL2BIT(my_var, 1);
SET_VAL6BIT(my_var, 5);
int a = GET_VAL2BIT(my_var); /* a == 1 */
int b = GET_VAL6BIT(my_var); /* b == 5 */
```