# create an array with just 2 bit for each cell in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, bit

I want create an array that each cell of it just have 2 bit in C++. is there any way to do this?

there is some method for creating bit array, but they allot just one bit to each cell.

Comment: What is the use of 2 bits per cell? Can you add context? Perhaps we can offer a better solution...

Comment: Not out of the box using the standard library, but it's easy enough to create a class that does this.

Comment: How I can do it @Dukeling? Is there a way to write such a class?

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to write this from scratch:**

The basic idea that probably all bit-set implementations use is to have an `int[]` (or really any other integral type), and to use bit-wise operations to get or set specific bits.

I'm sure you can find plenty of open-source implementations online, one example is Java's [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) (available [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/BitSet.java)). You can probably find C++'s [`bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) somewhere as well.

The same idea would apply here - just rather than mapping some index to one bit, it would be mapped to two bits instead.

**If you can use standard library classes:**

Here's something I quickly put together.

I wrote a `twoBitSet` class that extends [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), which is essentially an array of bits; it then maps some supplied index to two bits in the `bitset`.

There's also a `twoBit` helper class - modifying the data using the `[]` operator without it is somewhat difficult.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

template <size_t N> 
class twoBit
{
  typedef typename std::bitset<2*N>::reference bitRef;
  bitRef a, b;
public:
  twoBit(bitRef a1, bitRef b1): a(a1), b(b1) {};
  const twoBit &operator=(int i) { a = i%2; b = i/2; return *this; };
  operator int() { return 2*b + a; };
};

template <size_t N> 
class twoBitSet : private std::bitset<2*N>
{
  typedef typename std::bitset<2*N>::reference bitRef;
public:
  twoBit<N> operator[](int index)
  {
    bitRef b1 = std::bitset<2*N>::operator[](2*index);
    bitRef b2 = std::bitset<2*N>::operator[](2*index + 1);
    return twoBit<N>(b1, b2);
  };
};

int main()
{
    twoBitSet<32> bs;
    bs[0] = 2;
    bs[1] = 3;
    bs[2] = 1;
    bs[3] = 0;
    std::cout << bs[0] << std::endl; // prints 2
    std::cout << bs[1] << std::endl; // prints 3
    std::cout << bs[2] << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << bs[3] << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

It's obviously fairly basic at the moment, it only allows the `[]` operator to be used and doesn't have any range checking.

Perhaps creating 2 `[]` operator functions (similar to `bitset`) would've been better - one just being an accessor, and one returning the `twoBit` object.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/XJwWeM).

Answer (score 1):

How about create a struct containing a 2 bit variable and a 6 bit one:

```
struct split
{
  uint8_t sixbits : 6;
  uint8_t twobits : 2;
}
```

then create a array of structs for that and only use the two bit part of the struct?

NB: Not tested... Got info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14600153/2-bits-size-variable).

Comment: The main advantage of having an array of 2-bit members is the memory saving, which this doesn't have (otherwise you may as well use an `int[]` / `char[]`).

Comment: If you are going to do this, why not use four bitfields of length 2 and div/mod 4 the access?

Answer (score 0):

[`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) has specialization you are looking for. You could then simply consider two consecutive array elements as one element of 2 bools or write up wrapper class for this if you are uncomfortable increment your index by 2 in loops. The problem with creating class with 2-bit variable is that it will still take up 8bits (1byte) as smallest variable size in C++ is 1byte.

Totally custom solution would be to create array of chars (8bit) and then use [shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx) to use all bits of each char. This would however be needlessly complex as you would then need to unshift them each time you were accessing the values (...and that's exactly how `std::vector<bool>` specialization works).

Comment: RAM is not "byte aligned": it depends on the processor.

Comment: @Dukeling assuming you are right, shouldn't the header be included in the size returned by `sizeof()`? `sizeof` empty class is 1 byte, class with bool is 1 byte as well. I know what you are saying is true for java but is it really the same for C++?

Comment: @Dukeling I tried to find any reference to what you are talking about and I wasn't able to. If you find any references on the topic (if indeed there is class header), send them over - I would be interested in reading on the topic.

Comment: @DanielSaska I may have been confusing Java and C++, I couldn't find any reference either.

Comment: In both C and C++, a byte is the unit of size measurements, and `char` is precisely one byte. However, it's _at least_ 8 bits, not necessarily _exactly_ 8 bits. `bool` could be the same size as `char` or `int`, but it can't be size 1/8th - sizes aren't fractional. As an advice, if you do use an array of larger type, use `unsigned` instead of `char`. That's usually more efficient. (Often, loading a char requires loading 32 bits and throwing away 24 bits)

Comment: Well @Daniel, Vector<bool> is not good because of its slowness and its structure. Assume an array that each one of its cell have 2 bit and I want exactly implement this. Speed is very important for me and on the another hand I don't want use further space. If I can do this by another language please let me know...

Comment: @Chavoosh speed and space are often trade-offs of each other and I am pretty sure this is the case as well. I am pretty sure that if you want simple and fast solution, you could as well just use array of `int`s. Even if you will have 1M of your 2-bit values, you are taking 8MB of memory instead of 2MB which is 400% but tbh you have no reason to be concerned about it on modern platform (unless you are on mobile). But that depends on what your application is, really.