# Create a 10-bit data type in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, types

Can create a 10 bit data type?  I can use `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, and so forth, but what if I want to use `uint10_t` or `uint12_t`? Is this possible?

Comment: The beauty of C++ is that with a little bit of elbow grease you can define any datatype your heart desires.

Comment: Hmm, what about a `std::bitset<10>`?

Comment: How would you want it to behave? How would you want it to be different than a uint_16?

Comment: You can't because there is no C/C++ language and the solution will be dramatically different (*although a [tag:c] solution might work in [tag:c++]*).

Comment: [10 or 12 bit field data type in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29529979/995714), [2 bits size variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14600153/995714), [Which C datatype can represent a 40-bit binary number?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9595225/995714)

Answer (score 6):

You can't have a type whose size isn't a multiple of bytes - so creating a 10-bit datatype is a nonstarter.

You can create a type which represents entities that contain 10 bits though: whether using `std::bitset<10>` or using a 10-bit bitfield in a 16-bit type:

```
struct uint10_t {
    uint16_t value : 10;
    uint16_t _     : 6;
};
```

In both cases, the type itself will be larger than 10 bits. So you wouldn't be able to create an array of 8 of them to fit into 10 bytes, for instance.

Comment: IIRC, the unused bitfield member doesn't have to be named. (Actually, it wouldn't even need to be included)

Comment: If a byte has 10 bits, this is no problem :-)