# Is there a way I can use a 2-bit size type instead of an int, by just plugging in the new type name instead of int?

Tags: c++, types, int, bit-fields

I have an application where I need to save as much of memory as possible. I need to store a large amount of data that can take exactly three possible values. So, I have been trying to use a 2 bit sized type.

One possibility is using bit fields. I could do

```
struct myType {
    uint8_t twoBits : 2;
}
```

This is a suggestion from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14600153/5987698).

However, everywhere where I have used `int` variables prior to this, I would need to change their usage by appending a `.twoBits`. I checked if I can create a bit field outside of a `struct`, such as

```
uint8_t twoBits : 2;
```

but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16373465/5987698) says it is not possible. However,that thread is specific to C, so I am not sure if it applied to C++.

Is there a clean way I can define a 2-bit type, so that by simply replacing `int` with my type, I can run the program correctly? Or is using bit fields the only possible way?

Comment: Targeting macros exist. Assuming you're using gcc. I'm sure the others have their own ways of doing it.
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_21.html
Specifically INT_TYPE_SIZE exists. Never tried to use it myself, so ymmv

Comment: You have two bits, but the structure is still one byte. An array of `myType` is going to be 4 times the minimum possible size. You may find yourself having to pack and unpack bits.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you. Is there a clean way to define myType so that the packing and unpacking can be done without changing any code outside?

Comment: Yes-ish. You wrap the packed bit array into a structure that looks like an array of ints. You can implement a `operator[]` that finds the correct byte for you and returns a reference to an instance of a proxy class that implicitly converts to and from an `int`  and has an `operator=` that knows how to convert an `int` into the correct spot in the bit array.  I don't have time to write one up and prove it works correctly right now, unfortunately. Sounds like it would be fun.

Answer (score 3):

CPU, and thus the memory, the bus, and the compiler too, uses only bytes or groups of bytes. There's no way to store a 2-bits type without storing also the other 6 remaining bits.

What you can so is define a struct that only uses some bits. But we aware that it will not save memory.

You can pack several x-bits types in a struct, as you already know. Or you can do bits operations to pack/unpack them into a integer type.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a clean way to define myType so that the packing and unpacking can be done without changing any code outside?

Comment: @GoodDeeds The problem is that when you retrieve a var (like `myContainer.GetVar`) you must also tell which data (of 4 possible) you want. You may have 4 different types `myType1`, `myType2` an so on, which refer to the positions. But it's going to be a mess if you don't take another cares.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a clean way I can define a 2-bit type, so that by simply
>   replacing int with `my` type, I can run the program correctly? Or is
>   using bit fields the only possible way?

You can try to make the struct as transparent as possible by providing implicit conversion operators and constructors:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N, typename T = unsigned>
struct bit_field {
    T rep : N;
    operator T() { return rep; }
    bit_field(T i) : rep{ i } { }
    bit_field() = default;
};

using myType = bit_field<2, std::uint8_t>;

int main() {
    myType mt;
    mt = 3;
    std::cout << mt << "\n";
}
```

So objects of type `my_type` somewhat behave like real 3-bit unsigned integers, despite having more than 3 bits.
Of course, the residual bits are unused, but as single bits are not addressable on most systems, this is the best way to go.

Comment: Thank you. To save residual bits, can I have 4 bit fields of size 2 bits each in a struct? If so, it is possible to dereference them like a normal array/vector, if I have a vector of `my_type` itself?

Comment: this looks a lot like `std::bitset` (which is indexable @GoodDeeds)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Yes, but it behaves rather like a fundamental type than, well, a set of bits, e.g. in terms of arithmetics, I/O etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that you will save anything with your existing structure, as the surrounding structure still gets rounded up to a whole number of bytes.

You can write the following to squeeze 4 2-bit counters into 1 byte, but as you say, you have to name them myInst.f0:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  ubyte_t  f0:2,
           f1:2,
           f2:2,
           f3:2;
} myInst;
```

In c and c++98, you can declare this anonymous, but this usage is deprecated. You can now access the 4 values directly by name:

```
struct 
{ // deprecated!
  ubyte_t  f0:2,
           f1:2,
           f2:2,
           f3:2;
};
```

You could declare some sort of template that wraps a single instance with an operator int and operator =(int), and then define a union to put the 4 instances at the same location, but again anonymous unions are deprecated. However you could then declare references to your 4 values, but then you are paying for the references, which are bigger than the bytes you were trying to save!

```
template <class Size,int offset,int bits>
struct Bitz
{
    Size ignore : offset,
         value : bits;
    operator Size()const { return value; }
    Size operator = (Size val) { return (value = val); }
};
template <class Size,int bits>
struct Bitz0
{   // I know this can be done better
    Size value : bits;
    operator Size()const { return value; }
    Size operator = (Size val) { return (value = val); }
};

static union
{   // Still deprecated!
    Bitz0<char, 2> F0;
    Bitz<char, 2, 2> F1;
    Bitz<char, 4, 2> F2;
    Bitz<char, 6, 2> F3;
};

union
{
    Bitz0<char, 2> F0;
    Bitz<char, 2, 2> F1;
    Bitz<char, 4, 2> F2;
    Bitz<char, 6, 2> F3;
} bitz;
Bitz0<char, 2>& F0 = bitz.F0; /// etc...
```

Alternatively, you could simply declare macros to replace the the dotted name with a simple name (how 1970s):

#define myF0 myInst.f0

Note that you can't pass bitfields by reference or pointer, as they don't have a byte address, only by value and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

A very minimal example of a bit array with a proxy class that looks (for the most part) like you were dealing with an array of very small integers.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class proxy
{
    uint8_t & byte;
    unsigned int shift;
public:
    proxy(uint8_t & byte,
          unsigned int shift):
              byte(byte),
              shift(shift)
    {

    }
    proxy(const proxy & src):
        byte(src.byte),
        shift(src.shift)
    {

    }
    proxy & operator=(const proxy &) = delete;
    proxy & operator=(unsigned int val)
    {
        if (val <=3)
        {
            uint8_t wipe = 3 << shift;
            byte &= ~wipe;
            byte |= val << shift;
        }
        // might want to throw std::out_of_range here
        return *this;
    }
    operator int() const
    {
        return (byte >> shift) &0x03;
    }
};
```

Proxy holds a reference to a byte and knows how to extract two specific bits and look like an `int` to anyone who uses it.

If we wrap an array of bits packed into bytes with a class that returns this proxy object wrapped around the appropriate byte, we now have something that looks a lot like an array of very small `int`s.

```
class bitarray
{
    size_t size;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;
public:
    bitarray(size_t size):
        size(size),
        data((size + 3) / 4)
    {

    }
    proxy operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return proxy(data[index/4], (index % 4) * 2);
    }
};
```

If you want to extend this and go the distance, [Writing your own STL Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758580/writing-your-own-stl-container) should help you make a fully armed and operational bit-packed array.

There's room for abuse here. The caller can hold onto a `proxy` and get up to whatever manner of evil this allows.

Use of this primitive example:

```
int main()
{
    bitarray arr(10);

    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    arr[3] = 1;
    arr[4] = 2;
    arr[5] = 3;
    arr[6] = 1;
    arr[7] = 2;
    arr[8] = 3;
    arr[9] = 1;

    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[4] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[5] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[6] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[7] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[8] << std::endl;
    std::cout << arr[9] << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I correct that `proxy` would not create a large memory overhead, since members of the class are being created only when accessing and destroyed after?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, build on top of bitset, something like:

```
#include<bitset>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<int N> 
class mydoublebitset 
{
public: 
    uint_least8_t operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return 2 * b[index * 2 + 1] + b[index * 2 ];
    }

    void set(size_t index, uint_least8_t store)
    {
        switch (store)
        {
        case 3:
            b[index * 2] = 1;
            b[index * 2 + 1] = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            b[index * 2] = 0;
            b[index * 2 + 1] = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            b[index * 2] = 0;
            b[index * 2 + 1] = 1;
            break;
        case 0:
            b[index * 2] = 0;
            b[index * 2 + 1] = 0;
            break;
        default:
            throw exception();
        }
    }
private:
    bitset<N * 2> b;
};

int main()
{

    mydoublebitset<12> mydata; 

    mydata.set(0, 0);
    mydata.set(1, 2);
    mydata.set(2, 2);

    cout << (unsigned int)mydata[0] << (unsigned int)mydata[1] << (unsigned int)mydata[2] << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Basically use a bitset with twice the size and index it accordingly. its simpler and memory efficient as is required by you.